# enable/disable radio buttons from drop down menu selection in razor

Tags: javascript, razor

I have a view like below

```
   @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Student, (List<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Students, new { @id = "inputtext", @class = "form-control"})

   <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Teacher, new { @class = "control-label col-sm-2" })
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Teacher, "1")<span>A Transfer</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Teacher, "2")<span>B</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Teacher, "3")<span>C</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        </div>
    </div>
```

I need a script that will enable/disable radio buttons based on specific drop down menu selections. if the dropdown has a value of 1, then all the radiobutton will be disabled. and if the dropdown does not have a value of 1, the radiobutton will be enabled. 
I'm confused doing it in the razor View. Please Help :)

Answer (score 0):

I have used this code to enable/disable the textbox depending upon dropdown selection   . Replace ("**NO**") with your's radio button name and also (opts.value == **'Y'**) Y with 1

```
function updateTextBox(opts) {
    var chks = document.getElementsByName("NO");

    if (opts.value == 'Y') {
        for (var i = 0; i <= chks.length - 1; i++) {
            chks[i].disabled = false;                
        }
    }
    else {
        for (var i = 0; i <= chks.length - 1; i++) {
            chks[i].disabled = true;
            chks[i].checked = false;  
        }
    }
}
```